# Delegates with same signature

Tags: c#, .net, oop, delegates, clr

My question is a bit similar to this one: [How to convert an action to a defined delegate of the same signature?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7830441/how-to-convert-an-action-to-a-defined-delegate-of-the-same-signature)

Why there is no implicit convertion between delegates with same signature. For example, code:

```
class Program
{
    private delegate void Foo1(int x);
    private delegate void Foo2(int x);


    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Foo1 foo1 = Console.WriteLine;
        Foo2 foo2 = Console.WriteLine;

        Call(foo1);

        Call2(foo2);
    }

    static void Call(Action<int> action)
    {
        action(10);
    }

    static void Call2(Foo1 action)
    {
        action(10);
    }
}
```

it does not compile because `there isn't implicit convertion from Action<int> to Foo1.`
But normaly it's the same thing. So it mean this names are *aliases*, not actualy names. So i think it was great idea to think about it like aliases. So in this case we have 3 aliases of a `delegate, that get one int value and returns nothing`. And this delegates are fully interchangeable one by another. But we don't have it. So question is: why? By signatures it's the same thing, and there isn't any implementation, so delegates with same signature are one and same with many aliases...

Is it C# defect or there are reasons for it? As to me, i don't see any.

Comment: I don't consider this a defect, personally, but this *is* why I get annoyed when people define their own delegates instead of just using `Action`/`Func`.

Answer (score 3):

There's no implicit conversion between those two delegates for the same reason that there's no implicit conversion between these two types:

```
public sealed class Foo1
{
    public string Value { get; set; }
}

public sealed class Foo2
{
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

Just because two classes have the same fields doesn't mean that you should be able to treat one as if it were another.  The same logic applies to delegates (which are also types, mind you).

There is semantic meaning applied to the creation of that type.  If someone created a `Foo1` they want it to be a `Foo1`, not a `Foo2`.  If they're going out of their way to use a `Foo1` where a `Foo2` is expected, it's a big red flag that even though the types appear similar, there is a semantic difference between these two types.  If the programmer knows something that the compiler doesn't, they can use an explicit conversion of some sort to indicate that they know what they're doing.

(The previous paragraph was intentionally written to apply equally to your delegates, and the classes I provided above.)

Comment: No. Classes can be partial, can be inherited an so on. For example i have Action<int,int,int>. I don't want to write simple/XML comment about what is it, i can simply write something like `MySpecialDelegate = Action<int,int,int>` and it's just a self-documenting code.  For classes it could be a nice functionalty, but for them it will be used not frequently, because almost ever this two classes **are not the same**, but delegates - are. When i'm writeng `using MyAlarmTimer = System.Timers.Timer` i don't mean 'a big red flag`, i just want to simplify some code and explain it without comments

Comment: Why i can't do the same here - i dunno. Like in this case it's just an alias, for running code there is no difference between them. And if all delegates in .Net was auto-convertible to Action/Func - it will be very nice

Comment: @AlexJoukovsky Not all methods with the same signature are the same.  It's quite possible that the semantic meaning of the method holds more to it.  *You* may not use different delegates to attach that semantic meaning, but that doesn't mean that nobody does, or that the language designers assumed that it shouldn't be done.  As for the classes being partial, that's not really relevant; once they get compiled by the compiler it's just one class definition.  As for being inherited, they can be sealed; I added that to my example if it makes you feel better.

Comment: "Not all methods with the same signature are the same". They have the same signature! It sounds like "Two mans, having same firstname, secondname and lastname and the same SIN but with different nicknames are not the same man"

Comment: @AlexJoukovsky First off, the methods *don't* need to have the same name.  Next, just because two people have the same name *doesn't* mean they're the same person.  That you think all methods that have the same signature do the same thing is...I don't even know what to say to that.  How many methods have you ever written that accept no arguments and return no values?  Did they all do the same thing?

Comment: Methods are not. But delegates are the same. So i'd like to finish it. I get your opinion and our dispute will change nothing. But imo it's stupid. I really think that only one delegates has is their signature, and delegates with same signature could be implicitly convert one to another. We always can do `delegate void MyDel(int x); Action<int> action = Console.WriteLine;  MyDel mydel = x => action(x);` but i can't write `MyDel mydel = action;` even if consider that it's just a convertion to method group